# How to create a chart using an uploaded CSV file as input?

Tags: 7, charts

I wish to generate a table and chart using an uploaded [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file (in Drupal 7).

I have uploaded the CSV file using the Feed Importer module and created a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module). The view uses a display format of 'Chart', which is one of the possible views 'styles' you will have after enabling the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module.

**My question**: I don't know how to apply this to the uploaded CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the [Google Chart API](http://drupal.org/project/chart) module with Views integration. Here is a post that might help you - [Add Charts To Your Drupal Site](http://radarearth.com/content/add-charts-your-drupal-site). It uses the Node Import module to create a node of statistics by way of importing a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

As a variation to creating charts using an "uploaded CSV file as input*" (as in your question), you could also "*paste the data contained in such CSV file to create charts from it*". That's something that's supported by  the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module (which already has an official release for both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8).

It is a graphical user interface, using the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) javascript library as its charting engine (which may require a commercial license though). It claims to support every Highcharts chart-type and option.

Some more details about this module:

- It defines a new content type (= *Chart*) used to add charts to your site.
- It creates a chart widget that can be used in your own content types.
- It integrates with the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and provides an editor button to add charts to your WYSIWYG content (*CKeditor* and *TinyMCE* are supported).
- It provides an intuitive interface to configure charts through the Easychart plugin.
- It supports pasting of CSV data to create charts from it.
- [overheid.vlaanderen.be](http://overheid.vlaanderen.be/bedrijfsinformatie/toegankelijke-websites) contains some real world examples of a Drupal website with some charts created with Easycharts (ignore the text on that page if you're not familiar with this language, just concentrate on the charts).

## Resources:

- [Module documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/easychart/tree/README.txt?h=8.x-3.x).
- [Video demonstration](https://vimeo.com/137681122).